# How to get the string position of the middle-most element within HTML content?

Tags: php, domdocument

I am working with news articles in HTML format, that come from a wysiwyg editor, and I need to find the middle of it, but in a visual/HTML context, meaning an empty place inbetween two root elements. Kind of if you wanted to split the article into two pages let's say, with the equal number of paragraphs on each when possible.

All root elements seem to come out as paragraphs, which was easy enough to count, a simple

```php
$p_count = substr_count($article_text, '<p');
```

Returns the total number of opening paragraph tags, and then i can look for the `strpos` of a `($p_count/2)`-th occurrence of a paragraph.

But the problem is embedded tweets, that contain paragraphs, which appear sometimes under `blockquote > p`, other times as `center > blockquote > p`.

So i turn to DOMDocument. This little snippet gives me the nth element that is the middle one (even if the elements are divs and not paragraphs, which is cool):

```php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($article_text);
$body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body');
$rootNodes = $body->item(0)->childNodes;

$empty_nodes = 0;
foreach($rootNodes as $node) {
    if($node->nodeType === XML_TEXT_NODE && strlen(trim($node->nodeValue)) === 0) {
        $empty_nodes++;
    }
}

$total_elements = $rootNodes->length - $empty_nodes;
$middle_element = floor($total_elements / 2);
```

But how do i now find the string offset of this middle element within my original HTML source, so that i can point to this middle place within the article text string? Especially considering that DOMDocument converts the HTML of what i gave it, into a full HTML page (with a doctype, and head and all that), so its output HTML is bigger than my original HTML article source.

Comment: Finding the correct string offset is not going to be easy, I think you’re better off if you insert a new node in the DOM at the position you determined. _“so its output HTML is bigger than my original HTML article source”_ - the `save` methods of DOMDocument allow you to specify which node you want to “export” again, so if you specify the body node there, you should not have to much excess data, and probably can just strip off `<body>` and `</body>` from the result using string functions.

Comment: @CBroe might be a good workaround, i'll try to work with that, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved it.

What i did was match all HTML tags from the article, using the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag of `preg_match_all`, which remembers at which character offset the pattern was matched. Then i looped through all of them sequentially, and counted which depth i'm in; if it's an opening tag, i count the depth `+1`, and for a closing `-1` (minding the self-closing tags). Every time the depth gets to zero after a closing tag, i count that as one more root element closed. If at the end i ended up at depth `0`, i assumed i counted correctly.

Now, i can take the number of root elements that i counted, divide by 2 to get the middle-ish one (+-1 for odd numbers), and look at the offset of the element at that index as reported by `preg_match_all` previously.

Complete code for that if anyone needs to do the same thing is below.

It might be sped up if the `is_self_closing()` function was written using a regex and then checking `in_array($self_closing_tags)`, instead of a `foreach` loop, but in my case it didn't make enough of a difference for me to bother.

```php
function calculate_middle_of_article(string $text, bool $debug=false): ?int {
    
    function is_self_closing(string $input, array $self_closing_tags): bool {
        foreach($self_closing_tags as $tag) {
            if(substr($input, 1, strlen($tag)) === $tag) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    $self_closing_tags = [
        '!--',
        'area',
        'base',
        'br',
        'col',
        'embed',
        'hr',
        'img',
        'input',
        'link',
        'meta',
        'param',
        'source',
        'track',
        'wbr',
        'command',
        'keygen',
        'menuitem',
    ];

    $regex = '/<("[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\'|[^\'">])*>/';
    preg_match_all($regex, $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    $debug && print count($matches[0]) . " tags found   \n";

    $root_elements = [];
    $depth = 0;

    foreach($matches[0] as $match) {
        if(!is_self_closing($match[0], $self_closing_tags)) {
            $depth+= (substr($match[0], 1, 1) === '/') ? -1 : 1;
        }
        $debug && print "level {$depth} after tag: " . htmlentities($match[0]) . "\n";

        if($depth === 0) {
            $root_elements[]= $match;
        }
    }

    $ok = ($depth === 0);
    $debug && print ($ok ? 'ok' : 'not ok') . "\n";

    // has to end at depth zero to confirm counting is correct
    if(!$ok) {
        return null;
    }

    $debug && print count($root_elements) . " root elements\n";

    $element_index_at_middle = floor(count($root_elements)/2);
    $half_char = $root_elements[$element_index_at_middle][1];
    $debug && print "which makes the half the {$half_char}th character at the {$element_index_at_middle}th element\n";

    return $half_char;
}
```